# is "connected" a private api?

Tags: ios, app-store

Is "connected" a private API? apple told me so.
Appstore was saying I have used a private API when I submit my app :

> Performance - 2.5.1
>
> Your app still uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> connected
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to remove any non-public APIs. If you have
>   defined methods in your source code with the same names as the
>   above-mentioned APIs, we suggest altering your method names so that
>   they no longer collide with Apple's private APIs to avoid your
>   application being flagged in future submissions.
>
> Additionally, if you are using third party libraries, please update to
>   the most recent version of those libraries. If you do not have access
>   to the libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled
>   binary using the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The
>   "strings" tool can output a list of the methods that the library calls
>   and "otool -ov" will output the Objective-C class structures and their
>   defined methods. These tools can help you narrow down where the
>   problematic code resides. You could also use the "nm" tool to verify
>   if any third-party libraries are calling these APIs.

Is this sure? or they made a mistake?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure sounds like a private API. Where did you find this API documented?

Comment: I changed all "connected" method name. and my app is approved finally.